# webpack devserver не обновляет страницу

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при запуске дев-сервера, он обновляет страницу при любых действиях в js файлах и sass. Но, когда я вношу какие то изменения в html разметку, он, почему-то, не обновляет страницу.

Настройки дев-сервера в вебпаке

```
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 8080,
        watchContentBase: true
    },
```

Полный файл с настройками вебпака:

```
const path = require('path');

/* *********** plugins *********** */ 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetWebpackPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;

const optimization = () => {

    const config = {};

    if(isProd) {
        config.minimizer = [
            new OptimizeCssAssetWebpackPlugin(),
            new TerserWebpackPlugin()
        ];
    }

    return config;
};

module.exports = {

    mode: 'development',

    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/main.js')
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },

    optimization: optimization(),

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 8080,
        watchContentBase: true
    },
    
    plugins : [
        /* *********** HTML Webpack plugin *********** */ 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Akaev webpack template',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/index.html'),
            inject: 'body'
        }),

        /* *********** Clean Webpack plugin *********** */ 
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css'
        }),

        /* *********** Copy webpack plugin *********** */ 
        // new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        //  patterns: [
        //      {
                    
        //          from: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/img'),
        //          to: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/img')
        //      },
        //      {
        //          from: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/fonts/'),
        //          to: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/fonts/'),
        //      }
        //  ]
        // })

    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            /* *********** Babel *********** */ 
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },

        ]
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, удалив строчку

```
contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
```

в настройках dev-server'а